# Why the output of Set in Pyomo is disordered?

Tags: pyomo

I am learning Pyomo and I have some questions regarding the use of Set.
Below is the code:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

model = ConcreteModel()

model.A = pe.Set(initialize=[4,8,10,7])

print(model.A.pprint())
print(model.A.data())
```

---

Output:

A : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=4, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=(4, 10)
    [4, 7, 8, 10]

None

{8, 10, 4, 7}

By using model.A.pprint(), the output is [4,7,8,10]

But with model.A.data(), the output is {8,10,4,7}

I am wondering why this situation would happen.